# carry out disinfection

Tags: articles

*Carry out the/a disinfection with/by this detergent.*

I would like to ask: Is it supposed to be the article before "Disinfection"? What preposition is appropriate before "detergent".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends on context. If you are already talking about a specific (presumably planned) disinfection, it may be appropriate to use the definite article:

> When it is time to disinfect the equipment, carry out **the** disinfection with this detergent.

On the other hand, when it is more hypothetical or less specific, the indefinite article may be appropriate:

> If you wish, you may carry out **a** disinfection with this detergent.

You want to use **with** as the preposition in the sample sentence. However, there are other circumstances where **by** would also be acceptable:

> Following disinfection with compound alpha...
>
> Following disinfection by compound alpha...

With is a slightly less ambiguous choice in most such instances, however, as *by* will also be used (with limited other choices) when talking about an actor with agency (a person, animal, organisation, etc.):

> Following disinfection by HAZMAT staff...

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you what you want to say, both articles are ok (as long as you use one).

The correct preposition is "with".